# Angularjs: fire function if datepicker values are invalid

Tags: angularjs

I've assigned min and max values for datepicker https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker and it worked.
However,  also, I want to disable submit button if the date values are invalid.
When I tried to use `ng-change`, It failed because the function `onChange()` doesn't fire if the values are invalid, because `myDate` doesn't change in this case.
How can I do that? to fire function if the date values are invalid?

**Snippet Added**

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial"])
.controller("main", function($scope){

  $scope.myDate = new Date();

  $scope.minDate = new Date(
   $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
   $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
   $scope.myDate.getDate());

  $scope.maxDate = new Date(
   $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
   $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
   $scope.myDate.getDate());
  
$scope.InvalidDate = false;
$scope.onChange = function(date){
  //this function executes only if the date is valid 
 console.log(date);
}
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.3.7/angular-material.css"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="main">
  <md-datepicker ng-model-options="{allowInvalid : true}"

           ng-model="myDate" 
           md-min-date="minDate" 
           md-max-date="maxDate"

           ng-change="onChange(myDate)">
</md-datepicker>

<md-button ng-disabled="InvalidDate">submit</md-button>
</div>
```

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following code. button will be disabled if datepicker contains errors.

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial"])
    .controller("main", function($scope){

      $scope.myDate = new Date();

      $scope.minDate = new Date(
       $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
       $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
       $scope.myDate.getDate());

      $scope.maxDate = new Date(
       $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
       $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
       $scope.myDate.getDate());
      
    $scope.InvalidDate = false;
    })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.3.7/angular-material.css"/>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="main">
    <form name="myForm">
      <md-datepicker name="myDateField"
               ng-model="myDate" 
               md-min-date="minDate" 
               md-max-date="maxDate">
      </md-datepicker>
      <md-button ng-disabled="myForm.myDateField.$error.mindate || myForm.myDateField.$error.maxdate">submit</md-button>
      {{ myForm.myDateField.$error | json }}
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to use the button as follow:

```
<md-button ng-disable="myDate > maxDate || myDate < minDate">submit</md-button>
```

In this case you also don't do something with onChange()

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work, because if you  enter invalid date, `myDate` doesn't assign to that invalid one. for example, if the current date is 1-1-2016 and it's valid, so `$scope.myDate=1-1-2016`. But, then if you choose 1-1-2017 and it's invalid, then `my date` will not change its past value which is `$scope.myDate=1-1-2016`

Comment: but man if you say that myDate doesn't change, it means that you a problem in binding not in the directive itself. can you provide some code from controller ?

Comment: I did @NadeemKhoury

Comment: I'm trying to make a snippet or jsfiddle @NadeemKhoury

Comment: Now, if you enter date 1-1-2014 in the snippet, the console will not show anything @NadeemKhoury

Comment: because on `ng-min-date` and `ng-max-date` `myDate` will not be updated if it is invalid. when you remove those attributes from `md-datepicker` you can enable/disable the button as I wrote in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for your problem.

There is an directive in `md-datapicker` called `ng-model-options`
"**Allows tuning of the way in which ng-model is being updated. Also allows for a timezone to be specified."** However, in this `ng-model-options` there is a key called `allowInvalid:` **boolean value which indicates that the model can be set with values that did not validate correctly instead of the default behavior of setting the model to undefined.** So set this option and tell me if it solved your problem.

Refernces:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#usage,
- https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker

Comment: md-datepicker seems to ignore ng-model-options. Or at least allowInvalid.